# Query all *my* posts to a Facebook group's feed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.7

I can use https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.7/group/feed to obtain all posts to a group's feed. Is it possible to query only those posts which have been made by "me"?

I don't want to manually filter a huge result set.

Comment: No. (And the fact that SO demands a certain comment length doesn't change anything about that.)

Comment: @CBroe: OK, too bad...manual filtering it is. If you want to formulate an answer, I'm happy to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time of my answer (Facebook Graph API v2.8) there seems to be no way of filtering by `from.id`.